# Reduce rounding error of sum of square of floats

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, numerical

I try to calculate the sum of square of an array of float.

How to reduce the rounding error?

I am trying to sum about 5,000,000 floats in the inner loop of my actual program.

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
template <typename Sum, typename Element>
Sum sum(const size_t st, const size_t en) {
    Sum s = 0;
    for (size_t i = st; i < en; ++ i) {
        s += Element(i)*Element(i); 
    }
    return s;
}
int main() {
    size_t size = 100000;
    std::cout << "double, float: " 
              << sum<double, float>(0,size) << "\n";
    std::cout << "int, int: " 
              << sum<int, int>(0,size) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
double, float: 3.33328e+14
int, int: 216474736
```

Comment: probably will read more about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm after I get back to home.

Comment: Sort them and start from the smallest.

Comment: `size_t size = 100000;` is now a bit too much for `int`.

Comment: If your int is 32 bit then the integer calculation is wrapping

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/63

Comment: with `sum<long long, long long>(0,size)` I get 333,328,333,350,000.  So definitely overflow with int.

Comment: @EJP: sorting not help very much. When the partial sum gets very high value all remaining summands will does nothing

Comment: Accumulate into "buckets" until the value in a bucket is too large (compared to the value being added), then start a new bucket, keep doing this until you reach the end of the original sequence.  Then repeat using the same method to add up the buckets.  Repeat until only 1 bucket is left.

Comment: @AlexP. It helps a lot more than not sorting, unless you're using Kahan or pair-wise or similar.

Comment: By curiosity, why do you need to accumulate these five million numbers ?

Comment: You could try Kahan summation; see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of the floats is known, such as IEEE, then an array indexed by the exponent of a float can be used to store partial sums, then summed up to produce the total sum. During the array update, only floats with the same exponent are added together and stored into the array in the appropriate location. The final summation goes from smallest to largest. For C++, the array and functions could be members of a class.

Example for floats where the array is passed as a parameter to the functions:

```
/* clear array */
void clearsum(float asum[256])
{
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        asum[i] = 0.f;
}

/* add a number into array */
void addtosum(float f, float asum[256])
{
size_t i;
    while(1){
        /* i = exponent of f */
        i = ((size_t)((*(unsigned int *)&f)>>23))&0xff;
        if(i == 0xff){          /* max exponent, could be overflow */
            asum[i] += f;
            return;
        }
        if(asum[i] == 0.f){     /* if empty slot store f */
            asum[i] = f;
            return;
        }
        f += asum[i];           /* else add slot to f, clear slot */
        asum[i] = 0.f;          /* and continue until empty slot */
    }
}

/* return sum from array */
float returnsum(float asum[256])
{
float sum = 0.f;
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        sum += asum[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Is there any mathematical derivation for error estimation of such method?

Comment: @AlexP. - All the intermediate adds involve two floats with the same exponent. If both floats have the same sign, the exponent of the sum is 1 greater than the exponent of the two floats, and rounding occurs at the 24th bit of the 24 bit mantissa (msb == 1 and not stored), so the error in the resulting mantissa could be +/- (1^2(-25)), since the mantissa only has 24 bits. The overall error would depend on the effects of the rounding.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the type `int` for `Element`, there is an overflow on the square for each `i` after `std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())`, which could be `46341` on your system.
There is also an overflow on the sum when it reaches `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

You could use the type `long` or `long long` instead of `int` to increase this number.

It is also a good idea to store or cast the first `float` into a `double` or `long double` before multiplying to reduce the error on the floating point square operation as well.
Rounding on the last steps of a set of computations gives always a better result than rounding on the early steps, because you avoid to propagate (and increase) the representation errors on your internal computations.

If you really want precision, and do not want to reinvent the wheel using some complicated techniques, you can use a multi-precision library like `GNU Multi-Precision Library` or `Boost Multiprecision` :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software

They are more precise that the `long double` type of your system

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is add up squares of consecutive values, use the formula `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`to calculate the sum of the squares of all values from `1` to `n`.

That eliminates most effects of rounding as long as you use a type that can represent the result.   For example;

```
 template<typename Sum> Sum sumsq(size_t n)
 {
     // calculates sum of squares from 1 to x
     //   assumes size_t can be promoted to a Sum

     Sum temp(n);     // force promotion to type Sum
     return temp * (temp + 1)* (2*temp + 1)/6;
 }

 template<typename Sum> Sum alternate_sum(size_t st, size_t en)
 {
        Sum result = sumsq(en - 1);
        if (st > 0) result -= sumsq(st-1);
        return result;
 }

 int main()
 {
     size_t size = 100000;
     std::cout << "double, float: " 
              << alternate_sum<double>(0,size) << "\n";
     std::cout << "int, int: " 
          << alternate_sum<long long>(0,size) << "\n";
 }
```

Note that, for `size` equal to `100000`, using `int` to hold the result gives undefined behaviour (overflow of a signed integral type).

The `-1`s in the `alternate_sum()` reflect your loops being of the form `for (size_t i = st; i < en; ++ i)`

You could eliminate the use of the `size_t` type as a fixed feature, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

BTW:  since you say this code is in an inner loop, it's worth noting that this formula will be significantly faster than the loops you have been using.

Comment: actually i am summing floats between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: Your question neither said nor demonstrated that.   People aren't mindreaders, and can generally only ask a question actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

A float has 24 significant bits, while a double has 53 of them. So you have 29 guard bits, which is about 100 times more than 5000000.

So rounding errors will only arise for values which are 100 times smaller than the largest.

Also note that in the Intel architecture, the floating-point registers actually hold extended precision numbers on 80 bits, of which 63 are significant.

Then only numbers smaller than 100000 times the largest will incur truncation.

Should you really worry ?

Comment: thanks. will just debug the rest of the program before going back to this. but i think that situation can happen when i compare the partial sum and the next value to add. i use float to save memory.